# Understanding Greedy Matching in R

Tags: r, matching, greedy

I'm attempting my first matched pairs analysis, using greedy matching. I've been following along with a Coursera class example, but I'm not sure if I should be happy with the results of the matching.

Here's what I'm running for a greedy match:

```
    library(Matching)

    set.seed(123)

    n = 1500
    id <- 1:n

    score <- rnorm(n, mean=.5, sd=.13)
    location <- sample(c("A","B"),n, replace=TRUE)

    treatment <- rep(0,n)
    tr_subset <- sample(n, n*.1)
    treatment[tr_subset] = 1

    outcome <- rep(0,n)
    ot_subset <- sample(n, n*.63)
    outcome[ot_subset] = 1

    data_set <- data.frame(id,location,score,treatment,outcome)

    #prepare for matching
    loc_a <- as.numeric(location =="A")
    loc_b <- as.numeric(location =="B")

    prematch <- cbind(loc_a,loc_b,score,treatment,outcome)
    prematch <- data.frame(prematch)

    #variables that will be used for matching
    xvars<-c("loc_a","loc_b","score")

    #greedy matching
    greedymatch<-Match(Tr=treatment,M=1,X=prematch[xvars])

    matched<- 
    prematch[unlist(greedymatch[c("index.treated","index.control")]),]
```

I'm coming across the following "issues".

- Even though I'm setting M=1, I'm getting multiple matches to 1 treatment. For example, here's one being matched to 4 controls:

**Treatment**

|  | loc_a | loc_b | score | treatment | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 282 | 1 | 0 | .544612 | 1 | 0 |
| 282.1 | 1 | 0 | .544612 | 1 | 0 |
| 282.2 | 1 | 0 | .544612 | 1 | 0 |
| 282.3 | 1 | 0 | .544612 | 1 | 0 |

**Control**

|  | loc_a | loc_b | score | treatment | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 760 | 1 | 0 | .545 | 0 | 1 |
| 1045 | 1 | 0 | .545014 | 0 | 1 |
| 1060 | 1 | 0 | .544711 | 0 | 0 |
| 1241 | 1 | 0 | .544997 | 0 | 1 |

- Also, in cases where the treatment is matched to multiple controls, it creates multiple duplicate rows of the treatment (see above)
- Some people in the control group are being matched to more than one person in the treatment group:

**Treatment**

|  | loc_a | loc_b | score | treatment | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 644 | 1 | 0 | .480298 | 1 | 0 |
| 1139 | 1 | 0 | .480262 | 1 | 0 |
| 1206.1 | 1 | 0 | .48056 | 1 | 0 |
| 1218.1 | 1 | 0 | .480588 | 1 | 0 |

**Control**

|  | loc_a | loc_b | score | treatment | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1404 | 1 | 0 | .48038 | 0 | 1 |
| 1404.1 | 1 | 0 | .48038 | 0 | 1 |
| 1404.2 | 1 | 0 | .48038 | 0 | 1 |
| 1404.3 | 1 | 0 | .48038 | 0 | 1 |

Are these problems I need to fix or just part of how greedy matching works?

I'm having trouble finding good examples for using Matched() in R for greedy matching. Also do you know of any good resources for greedy matching in general?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of several defaults in `Match()`.

The first scenario is due to the `distance.tolerance` and `ties` arguments to `Match()`. By default, `distance.tolerance` is `1e-5`, which means any control units within a distance of `1e-5` or less of a treated unit will be considered equally close to the treated unit. So, for example, control units 760, 1045, 1060, and 1241 are all within `1e-5` of treated unit 282. Because the `ties` argument is `TRUE` by default, any ties will be included in the match. Here, those four control units are tied, so they are all matched to that treated unit (and each pair is given a weight of .25). To prevent this from happening, you can set `ties = FALSE`, in which case one control unit will be selected to be matched to each treated unit. Setting `distance.tolerance = 0` also ensures that any differences between distances are respected and not rounded down to zero.

The second scenario is due to the `replace` argument, which is `TRUE` by default, so matching with replacement is performed. This means each control unit can be matched with multiple treated units if it is the closest to those treated units. To perform matching without replacement, which seems to be what you want, set `replace = FALSE`.

Note that `Matching` isn't the only package that does greedy matching; `MatchIt` does as well and has defaults that would be in line with what you would expect, though not all options are available. For example, by default, `Matching::Match()` performs Euclidean distance matching, whereas the default in `MatchIt::matchit()` is propensity score matching. Eucldiean distance matching in `MatchIt` requires some additional programming.